# Passing Values to Multiple Files in Gatling

Tags: scala, gatling

I am designing a software test using Gatling for my company's web based application.  After many iterations, I have come to a design that I believe will make it easy for testers at my company to easily change parameters as needed, but it is quite complex.  The main file which contains the scenario, setup, and simulation calls is all contained in one file that then connects to a different file via methods for each of the other functions we are testing.

My problem is when logging into our API with a request, using one of the function files, it sends a response that includes a session token.  It is important that I am able to pass the value of that token back to the main file, so that I can use it as a parameter in other function methods.  I am having a problem passing the actual value of this token to the main file.

Here is the sample code for the method:

```
object BasicLogin {
   def login ( hostparam:String, controlparam:String, usernameparam:String, passwordparam:String) : (ChainBuilder, String) = {

      val user = usernameparam

      val password = passwordparam

      val host = hostparam
      val controlid = controlparam
      val logintype = "user"



      val jsonrequest = """{"logintype":"""" + logintype + """",
            "controlid":"""" + controlid + """",
            "user":"""" + user + """",
            "password":"""" + password + """",
            "host":"""" + host + """"
            }"""

      val loginChain = exec(http("Login")
          .post("sample.url.com")
          .body(StringBody(jsonrequest))
          .asJSON
          .check(jsonPath("$..result").is("true"))
          .check(jsonPath("$..session")
          .find
          .saveAs("currentSession")))

        val accessToken: String = exec(session => {
           val sessionid = session("currentSession").as[String]
           println("token: " + sessionid)
           session })  
           .toString

        return (loginChain, accessToken)
    }
}
```

Here is my code calling the method for login:

```
val host = "IPaddress"
  val controlid = "IDcontroller"
  val username = "JDoe"
  val password = "TerriblePassword"

  val result = BasicLogin.login(host, controlid, username, password)
  val basiclogin:ChainBuilder = result._1
  val currentSession:String = result._2

  println("Session: " + currentSession)
  println("Login: " + basiclogin)
```

And here is what I get in response:

```
Session: ChainBuilder(List(io.gatling.core.action.builder.SessionHookBuilder@6f70f32f))
Login: ChainBuilder(List(io.gatling.http.action.sync.HttpRequestActionBuilder@3dd69f5a))
```

I have searched in many different places, and have not found much in terms of similar issues.  I know Gatling is run in multi-cast, and not sure if this is even possible.  I have utilized the save as method, and tried calling the value using Gatling DSL, but no luck.  I originally was trying to use just values without methods, but that failed miserably.  I have also tried the set method and mapping, but neither of these worked either.

So now I am trying to get a value from the response, and return it back to the main file using the method.  It runs, but it returns the chainbuilder.

Any advice?

Rob

Comment: I don't know what's causing that, but if each Gatling user should have their own token, then surely it would be easiest to just save it in the session, then any other requests created for that user could just access it directly from their session. If all users should share the same token, then couldn't your `BasicLogin` object just expose the token via another method or val?

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Yes, each user should have their own token, and I have saved it in the session using the **.saveAs("currentSession")** method, but I have not succeeded in pulling the value from this session attribute.  I have tried to call it using **session("currentSession")**, **session => session "currentSession"**, and **"${currentSession}"**.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Put your `saveAs` in a `check`, e.g. `.check(jsonPath("$..token").saveAs("my_token"))`, then it should be accessible: `exec(s => { println(s("my_token").as[String]); s })`

Comment: `.check(jsonPath("$..session")
          .find
          .saveAs("currentSession"))`

Thanks for the suggestion.  I did attempt using the saveAs in a check, and also attempted calling the session attribute in the same manner as you have modeled.  Still no luck.